# Distinguishing between storage model and conceptual model field names (Entity Framework)

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, storage, conceptual

Every sample I come across has the entities and properties in the storage model named exactly the same as in the conceptual model. So in the mapping section, I can't tell whether an entity or property is from the storage model or conceptual model.

This is a snippet of an Entity Framework diagram. Which "ID" fields are from the database and which are from the entities?

```
<AssociationSetMapping Name="FK_Orders_Customers" TypeName="ContosoModel.FK_Orders_Customers" StoreEntitySet="Order"> 
  <EndProperty Name="Customer">
    <ScalarProperty Name="ID" ColumnName="CustomerID" />
  </EndProperty>
  <EndProperty Name="Order">
    <ScalarProperty Name="ID" ColumnName="ID" />
  </EndProperty>
</AssociationSetMapping>
```

Comment: Difference between  storage model and conceptual model ? If conceptual model is the classes generated by EF then what is storage model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well only databases have Columns, so ColumnName is the Database Name.
Name is from the Entity (or in this case the Association).

Hope this helps
Alex